# Node.js framework with sessions support in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, frameworks, mongodb, node.js, v8

I am looking for a node.js framework which is capable of tracing user sessions via cookies/storage on the server side.

Storage has to be in MongoDB

Comment: A 'user session' can be anything, depending on your requirements. I doubt you'll find any framework that will fulfill your needs. But it could be fairly easily implemented using native drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the express framework. http://expressjs.com/ it is built on the connect middleware which has several middleware providers for the features you are after.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find the example of code how MongoDB storage should be instantiated. If you know where to find that that'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the express framework, and to use MongoDB storage you will need [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb). It does exactly what you're looking for and no more.